# NASM: variable is not changing

Tags: assembly, nasm

I need to change first variable's value to second but code that i wrote is not working.
I tried this:

```
mov DWORD [enety_26500], enety_26501
```

but program still prints me *"Hello, world!"*

Can anyone help?

```
        global _main
        extern _ExitProcess@4
        extern _printf
        section .text
_main:
        call main
        pop eax
        push    0
        call    _ExitProcess@4
        ret
print:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov eax, [ebp+8]
        push eax
        call _printf
        pop ebp
        push 0
        ret
main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        push enety_26500
        call print
        pop eax
        mov DWORD [enety_26500], enety_26501
        push enety_26500
        call print
        pop eax
        pop ebp
        push 0
        ret

        section .data

        enety_26500:
                dw 'Hello, world!', 10, 0

        enety_26501:
                dw 'Hello,', 10, 0
```

Comment: `mov DWORD [enety_26500], enety_26501` <-- All that does is overwrite the first 4 bytes located at `enety_26500` with the address of `enety_26501`.

Comment: thanks, but if i put mov DWORD [enety_26500], [enety_26501] it shows me error

Comment: That's not a valid combination of operands. And even if it was it wouldn't help, since strings don't have a fixed size.

Comment: how to make valid and solve it? please, help

Comment: It's not clear what you're _really_ trying to solve. I mean, if you just wanted to print the second string you could just do `push enety_26501`.

Comment: You can't do what you think you can do (if that makes sense). If you want to have a variable which holds the address of a string and that can be changed at will, then you need another storage location to hold that variable.

Comment: i can use `db` too it does not matter.

Comment: so how to make it?

Comment: As others have said, this is an odd thing to do. But to start with, you should have `push dword [enety_26500]` not `push enety_26500` before your second `print` call. And for your strings you should be using `db` not `dw`.

Comment: i've tried, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you are trying to do. It looks like you are trying to do this (in C, using clearer names):

```
const char *stra = "hello world";
const char *strb = "hello";
...

printf(stra);
stra = strb;
printf(stra);
```

The thing is, you can't have a label telling you where a string is located and then try to change the label. It doesn't make sense - a label isn't a container or a location in itself, it's just... a label. Either store the label in eax and change eax or store the label in another variable:

```
    push    DWORD PTR sptr
    call    printf
    mov     eax, strb
    mov     DWORD PTR sptr, eax

    push    DWORD PTR sptr
    call    printf
    ....

sptr:
    .long   stra
stra:
    .string "hello world"
strb:
    .string "hello"
```

Something like that anyway!

Edit: Just out of interest: If you wanted to change stra, and stra was stored in a writeable data segment (ie: .data), you could do:

```
mov     BYTE PTR stra+5, 0
```

which would write a 0 just after the "hello" part and terminate the string at that point. Calling printf directly on stra would print "hello" then.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question, can i just edit stra's value?

Comment: Note the difference between stra (effectively a number giving you the location of the "h" in "hello world" and [stra], which is the actual "h" in hello world. Anyway, If the string is in the data segment, yes you can change it. Often a C compiler will put strings in a read only segment and then writing to them will cause a fault.

Comment: Pointers and addresses can be a little confusing in C, never mind assembly. I find the website "godbolt.org" quite helpful to show me how a C compiler renders code into assembly. If you select x86-64 gcc from the list, you'll need to add "-m32" to the compiler options to get 32 bit assembly. Try -O to see how it optimises it etc. Interesting if assembly is your thing :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot) Sorry but how to change it?

Comment: This is a NASM question; you're using GAS's MASM-like `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  So you need `mov [sptr], eax`.  (Except `mov eax, strb` is obviously supposed to be a `mov eax,imm32` with the immediate address, not a load.  In NASM syntax, it is, but in GAS syntax like the rest of the code you'd need `mov eax, OFFSET strb`.)  But you could just `mov [sptr], OFFSET strb`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I should have known someone would notice that! I would normally use GAS type syntax but I was trying to half do Nasm syntax (which I don't know) and ended up in a bit of mess. It's been long enough that my impulse with offset is to wonder where the data segment is :-)